# Question about using find, grep FreeBSD 2.5.1, and returning filenames from returned results

Tags: macos, terminal, scripting, grep, openssl

This feels like a super specific use case, but still looking for ideas.

1. I'm running the `/usr/bin/security find-certificate -a -c $USER -Z -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain` command on a machine that returns a crap ton of results.
2. That returns a huge file of certificate info, but I figured out a way to split that file based on `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and put each one of those certificates into individual files beginning with the word `cert` like `certaa`, `certbb` and so on and so forth
3. I then run the find command on any files in the working directory that begin with the word `cert` which should be all of them, and then run the openssl x509 command on each of those returned files like so: `find . -name "*cert" -type f -exec openssl x509 -text -noout -in {} \; | grep -n "Not After"`
4. I'm piping those results to grep because I need to see just the information with the "Not After" which tells me the date the certificate expires
5. The command and pipe to grep works and returns the results I'm looking for and shows the line numbers, but it doesn't return the filename that the result was found in.

I did see that you can include -H which should show the filename, or `--show-filename` parameter but it doesn't, it just shows `standard-input` instead of the filename. I'm guessing because it's the standard input of the find command and results returned. I need to find the filename because I need to know which cert has expired and which one I need to delete.

Hope that super complicated explanation makes sense. Basically I'm looking for a way for the returned results to show the filename the grep results return, instead of standard input.

Comment: So, you need `grep -l "Not After"`, right?

Comment: yea I tried that, when I do that the ONLY thing that gets returned is `(standard input)` not even my returned results

Comment: potentially? let me try that. thanks @rowboat

Answer (score 0):

Using complex commands with `find ... -exec` tends to get messy fast. If the files are all in a single directory, what about using something like this:

```
for certfile in cert*; do
    openssl x509 -text -noout -in "$certfile" | 
        sed -n "/Not After/ s/^/$certfile:/p"
done
```

Explanation: since the contents of the loop run in the full shell (not just as simple commands, like `find -exec` can do), you can use and manipulate variables (`$certfile`) however you want. The `sed` command skips printing most of the file (the `-n` option), but on lines containing "Not After", it replaces the beginning of the line (`^`) with the filename and a colon, then prints that line.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Gordon! That seems to do the trick